# Group-by with multiple variables

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a df that looks a bit like this:

```
Date   Animal   Height   Weight
Jan-00   Cat      102      56
Jan-00   Cat      98       75
Jan-00   Cat      50       100
Jan-00   Cat      46       46
Jan-00   Cat      100      50
```

I am trying to find the average weight of cats in Jan-00 that are more than the median height of Cats in Jan-00. So in this example, the median height is 98; and the average weight of cats more than the median height is 53 (avg of 50, 56). I have a variable number of different animal types so I don't want to have to manually specify the animal types. In time there will be other things I want to measure over and above the weight of the cats (so I'm trying to future proof my code somewhat).

From scouring StackOverflow, my approach has been:
(1) Write a function which tells the rest of the code which things I want to measure:

```
def column_index(df, query_cols):
    cols = df.columns.values
    sidx = np.argsort(cols)
    return sidx[np.searchsorted(cols,query_cols,sorter=sidx)]

cols = (column_index(df, ["Weight"]))
```

Then (2), write some code that splits my original df between dates and animal type, split by the median height, and then return the things I want to measure:

```
x = (df["Height"]
     .gt(df.groupby(["Date","Animal"])["Height"]
     .transform('median')))

df_Tall = df[x].mean(level = 0)[df.columns[cols]]
```

However, when I do this, it is only returning a single series of data for the weight; I'm trying to get multiple columns, each of which represent a different animal - ie my intended output should look like:

```
       Weight
Date   Cat   Animal_x   Animal_y   Animal_z
Jan-00  53     xx          xx         xx
```

I think my error likes in the line

```
.gt(df.groupby(["Date","Animal"])["Height"]
```

But I can't figure out how to fix it. Any thoughts would be really appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Why not filter out the animals having heights greater than their group median first? Is performance an issue in your case?

Comment: At the moment, I'm not overly fussed about the speed of the calculation (within reason!). 
I had thought that the term 
x = (df["Height"].gt(df.groupby(["Date","Animal"])["Height"].transform('median')))
Would accomplish that?
Is there something more straightforward that I am overlooking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach was almost correct. I just added another `groupby` of the median-filtered height data to group the mean weight (and height) by the `Animal` and `Date` columns:

```
df.loc[
    df['Height'].gt(df.groupby(['Date', 'Animal'])['Height'].transform('median')), :
].groupby(['Date', 'Animal']).mean().unstack()
```

Of course you can get the mean of the `Weight` by selecting the `Weight` column after (or also before) the second `groupby`, f.i. by changing the last line to: `].groupby(['Date', 'Animal'])[['Weight']].mean().unstack()`, with the double brackets around `'Weight'` retaining the df dimensions/structure.

step-by-step:

- groupby Date and Animal, get median and select where Height is greater (same as in your question)
- `.loc` explicit first axis indexing over your `df[x]` is just my personal preference. both work well to filter the data by the median height.
- second groupby on height-filtered data, selecting Weight before or after groupby is optional.
- get the mean of each animal and date group
- unstack transforms the dataframe into multiindex-columns with Animal as the second level

The second groupby could afaik only be avoided, if `groupby.median()` supported a `level`-argument. But since `level` is not supported by (most or all?) groupby methods, a second groupby is required.

Comment: That is fantastic. Thank you SO MUCH!!